# Images same size - scaling proportional

Tags: css, wordpress, image

Im in trouble with getting the image sized well. The Size how you see fits now, but they are not scaled proportional. Do you know how to cut the images if they are too big?

http://vintagemaedchen.de

```css
.post-img {
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.post-img img {
 max-width:100%;
 height:245px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background.

```
Background-size: cover;
Background-position: center;
Background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to say its a WordPress Site:

Http://vintagemaedchen.de
Cant set it as a background

Comment: You could get the thumbnail url  and use it as a inline style for the background.